# how do you loop over text files in python

Tags: python, loops

I need a help with looping over files:

```
inputa = int(input('How many days of data do you have? '))
print('Average Temperatures:')

if inputa == 1:
  lst1 = []  
  lst = []  

  for line in open('temps1.txt'):
    lst1.append(line.rstrip())
  lst = lst1      

elif inputa == 2:
  lst1 = []
  lst2 = []
  lst = []

  for line in open('temps1.txt'):
    lst1.append(line.rstrip())

  for line in open('temps2.txt'):
    lst2.append(line.rstrip())

  lst = lst1+lst2

elif inputa == 3:
  lst1 = []
  lst2 = []
  lst3 = []
  lst = []

  for line in open('temps1.txt'):
    lst1.append(line.rstrip())

  for line in open('temps2.txt'):
    lst2.append(line.rstrip())

  for line in open('temps3.txt'):
    lst3.append(line.rstrip())

lst = lst1 + lst2 + lst3
```

Is there a way to loop over files. For example, I want them to be `temps1.txt`, `temps2.txt`, `temps3.txt` and so on depending on the user's input. I also want to have `lst1[]`, `lst2[]`, `lst3[]` and so on.

Comment: How about something like `files=['temps1.txt', 'temps2.txt', 'temps3.txt']` and then `for i in range(int(inputa)):` and then opening file one by one

Comment: @Bazingaa how do i put it?

Comment: You already got two answers below to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list of lists instead of separate lists. This helps in managing things better. Then loop through files and get contents into each sublist of the previously created list of lists.

```
inputa = int(input('How many days of data do you have? '))
print('Average Temperatures:')

lst = [[] for _ in range(inputa)]

for i in range(inputa):
    for line in open(f'temps{i+1}.txt'):
        lst[i].append(line.rstrip())

print(lst)  # List of lists.
print([item for sublist in lst for item in sublist])  # Flattened list.
```

Comment: what if i want to combine the list. You program ouput like this: ['a:2', 'b:3']['a:7','b:3']. Whereas, i want it to be ['a:2', 'b:3,'a:7','b:3'].

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
g=glob.glob("*") #This selects every file in directory, if you want the only the ones starting with "temps", then write "temps*"
for index, line in enumerate(g):
    print(g)
    #do stuff with files here
```

g is your list of files. The last for loop is just the looping over them. Does this help?

## modification after comments

this works for me:

```
import glob
g=[]
for x in range(inputdata):
    select = "*"+str(x)
    exp_g=glob.glob(select)
    g.extend(exp_g)
g
```

Comment: i want files depending on my input. if my user types in 2, then it should choose two files which are temp1 and temp2. Do you see the pattern in my codes.